# How to extend or merge Styled Components theme

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I have a Styled Components-based component library with its own set of theme settings that for the most part will never need to be overridden. I'm in the process of pulling this component library into another project that also uses Style Components and has its own theme. How can I import components from the component library and this project and ensure that each of them are only provided with theme values from their corresponding repo? I don't want to override my component library theme, I'd like to manage 2 separate themes so that my component library has access to a default theme and this other project can define a separate theme object for it's own components

Example: 
**Separate Project**

```
const theme = {
  colors: {
    error: '#f23f3f',
  }
}

import { SeparateProjectThemeProvider } from 'separate-proj';

class App extends React.Component {
 render () {
  return (
   <SeparateProjectThemeProvider theme={theme}>
     <h1>Hello</h1>
   </SeparateProjectThemeProvider>
  )
 }
}
```

**Component Library**

```
const theme = {
  colors: {
    brand: '#3bbdca',
  }
}

import { ThemeProvider } from "styled-components";

import defaultTheme from "./theme-settings";

const mergeThemes = (theme1, theme2) => {
  const mergedTheme = { ...theme1, ...theme2 };
  return mergedTheme;
};

const CustomThemeProvider = props => {
  const customTheme = {
    custom: Object.assign({}, defaultTheme)
  };

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={mergeThemes(customTheme, props.theme)}>
        {props.children}
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};

export default CustomThemeProvider;
```

Comment: Approximately how many components are in your component library?

Comment: If both themes define the same property (e.g. one defines the error color as red and the other defines it as maroon) do you want them to use their respective values or do you want one to win over the other?

Comment: I have about 20 components. Ideally, I'd like them to keep their respective values

Comment: Would any of the components from your component library have components from the project nested within them? Would you often have scenarios like the following: <App><ProjComp1WithProjectTheme><LibComp1WithLibTheme><ProjComp2WithProjectTheme/></LibComp1WithLibTheme></ProjComp1WithProjectTheme></App> A possible case of that kind of nesting would be if your component library had a "Tab" or "Panel" component that you then placed child components from the main project inside of.

Comment: I don't see that happening, but it's possible. The component library, so far, is a small and simple library, that in most cases is used to build out bigger components across our company products

Answer (score 1):

The code below will demonstrate a couple options -- either pre-wrapping each of your component-lib components with the appropriate theme provider (WrappedTitle) or wrapping as you use them ("Hello Component World!" portion).

```
// Sample component-lib/index.js
import React from 'react';
import styled from "styled-components";
import {ThemeProvider} from "styled-components";

const theme = {
  titleColor: "green"
};
export const CompLibThemeProvider = props => {
  const customTheme = Object.assign({}, theme, props.theme);
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={customTheme}>
        {props.children}
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};

export const Title = styled.h1`
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  color: ${props => props.theme.titleColor};
`;
export const WrappedTitle = (props) => {
  return (<CompLibThemeProvider><Title {...props}/></CompLibThemeProvider>);
};
```

And here is some sample project code:

```
// App.js
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import {Title, CompLibThemeProvider, WrappedTitle} from 'component-lib';
import {ThemeProvider} from "styled-components";

const theme = {
  titleColor: "red"
};

export const BigTitle = styled.h1`
  font-size: 5em;
  text-align: center;
  color: ${props => props.theme.titleColor};
`;

const ProjectThemeProvider = props => {

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={Object.assign({}, theme, props.theme)}>
        {props.children}
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};
const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
    <ProjectThemeProvider>
      <>
        <BigTitle>Hello Big World!</BigTitle>
        <WrappedTitle>Hello Pre-wrapped World!</WrappedTitle>
      </>
    </ProjectThemeProvider>
    <CompLibThemeProvider><Title>Hello Component World!</Title></CompLibThemeProvider>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks going to implement this as soon as I address some other problems I'm having.